# How to define a column to be both primary key and self-incremented in Transact-sql?

Tags: t-sql

to define a column to be a primary key I do this

```
ContactID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

It looks like I need still to provide the value of the **ContactID** when inserting rows. I want primary key to be unique and incremented (+1) as if I defined the table using the designer.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
ContactID int not null identity(1,1) primary key
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts](
    [ContactID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Contacts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ContactID] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

you will have to add your other columns, etc.

UPDATE: as absolute minimum statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts(ContactID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: whats the table name, etc. so we can provide full create script?

Comment: Table name is Contacts, 2 other columns are FirstName, Lastname (both varchar(50)). It's just a test table to learn transact-sql

Comment: So to make it simple, "[ContactID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL" is what I need to make the ContactID column both primary and self incremented?

Comment: that only identifies it as auto increment by 1 starting at 1 identity column, you still need to specify the primary key